# Inject complex object into resource method in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I'm working on a RESTful service in Java 8. I have the following method in my resource class, which responds to `POST` requests.

```
@POST
public Response store(SomeType myInstance){ ... }
```

Typically, this get's deserialised without a hitch in case the `json` request can be directly mapped. However, `SomeType` in this case is a complex object containing other objects persisted in a database.

Is there a way to capture the request, figure out the type, build the object `SomeType` and then pass it through to the `store` method? I'm leaning towards some type of middleware, yet I'm not quite sure how the dependencies would work.

Note: For security reasons, I am very limited in 3rd party packages that I can use. So I can't use out of the box solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your use case can be solved with Jackson's [CustomDeserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) feature.

1. The general approach would be to create a class for each incoming type you need to support. Ex. **SomeType1**, **SomeType2**, **SomeType3**`.
2. All of these classes should extend the **SomeType** parent class.
3. The `SomeType` parent class should have a [CustomDeserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization).
4. In the [CustomDeserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) you can inspect the json fields to determine what type the json should be deserialized to.
5. Then you can use the [JsonParser.readValueAs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#readValueAs(java.lang.Class)) method to deserialize the json into the desired type **SomeType1**, **SomeType2**, or **SomeType3**.
6. If you need to fetch some more data from a database and populate fields of **SomeType1**, **SomeType2**, and **SomeType3** you can do that within your handler by checking the object type.

   ```
   @POST
   public Response store(SomeType myInstance) {
      if (myInstance instanceof SomeType1) {
        // fetch from database and populate more fields
      } else if (myInstance instanceof SomeType2) {
        ...
      }
      ...
   }
   ```